# Bind directory for Win32 api inside docker container

Tags: docker, winapi, windows-services, containers, c++17

Background:
I'm currently developing a windows service that monitors the file system for changes on a windows machine.

The next step is to put this app into a container so that it would run on every machine. For "catching" the directory changes, I use the function **ReadDirectoryChangesExW** in C++. Any change on the given directory will cause a windows event to be raised.

In order to start my container and test my service, I use the following command:

```
docker run --rm -it --workdir="c:\FileAgent" monitor
```

where **FileAgent** is the directory that I place my `.exe` in and **monitor** the name of my image.

By running the service to monitor a container's local directory, the service works fine. But when I try to monitor a folder on the host, through binding, the service is not working as **ReadDirectoryChangesExW** is FALSE and the app is crashing.

Code sample:

```
string lpDir = "C:/tmp/";
FILE_NOTIFY_EXTENDED_INFORMATION strFileNotifyInfo[1024];

HANDLE fileH = CreateFileA
(
    lpDir.c_str(),
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
    FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_ALWAYS,
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL
);
if (!fileH) ErrorReporter(L"Error in creating file handler");

OVERLAPPED ovl = { 0 };
ovl.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
if (!ovl.hEvent) {
    ErrorReporter(L"ERROR in creating event.");
    ExitProcess(GetLastError());
}

if (!ReadDirectoryChangesExW(
    fileH, (LPVOID)&strFileNotifyInfo, sizeof(strFileNotifyInfo),
    TRUE, //subtree watcher
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES,
    NULL, &ovl, NULL, ReadDirectoryNotifyExtendedInformation))
{
    ErrorReporter(L"Error in reading directory changes!");
    ExitProcess(GetLastError());
}
```

where **lpDir** is the path to the directory. To re-produce that state, I use the following command to start my container, after building the docker image:

```
docker run --rm -it --workdir="c:\FileAgent" -v c:\Users\john\Desktop\dataDir:c:\tmp\ monitor
```

As I tested, this is a two-way binding. Which means that changes to **dataDir** affect the **tmp** directory inside the container and vice versa. When I start the service, it crashes as I forementioned.

What I tried:

1. Starting the container with a specific user by using the flag `--user "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"`
2. Define a user during building through Dockerfile

   ```
   RUN NET USER my_admin /add

   RUN NET LOCALGROUP Administrators /add

   my_admin USER my_admin
   ```
3. First create the directory and then bind it.

Along all these experiments I noticed that the user on the container's bind folder is `...`. Also, I cannot delete this folder, which makes sense as the real folder is located on the host machine.

Could you please provide any advice?

Am I missing any security/access right issues?

Comment: *"**ReadDirectoryChangesExW** is NULL"* - What does that mean? Surely, the symbol is properly imported (i.e. it has a non-null address). Otherwise the application wouldn't even start. A [mcve] is required.

Comment: Edited my question and provided a few code. Thanks!

Comment: *`ReadDirectoryChangesExW` is FALSE* - what is `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` returned after this ?

Comment: You are calling `GetLastError` too late. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) on *when* to call it. Also, the path separator on Windows is a backslash, not a forward slash. And if you want to avoid running into unsolvable issues, call `CreateFileW` instead of `CreateFileA`. Regardless, an API call returning a failure code does not cause an application to crash.

Comment: @IInspectable noted what you said. This is weird. It's working for a local container dir but not for the connected one. The only explanation that I can give is that C:\tmp does not really exist on the container FS after binding.

Comment: @kothemel - `if (!fileH)`  wrong check. `CreateFileA` return on error `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (-1) but not 0.as result you not catch fail here and pass invalid handle to `ReadDirectoryChangesExW` and got `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE`

Comment: @RbMm i changed some of my code. Now I use the CreateFIleW, which returns 183 at GetLastError == ERROR_ALREADY_EXIST as the folder that i pass as argument exists. Now the real error occurs at ReadDirectoryChangesExW, which returns with 0 and GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION. According to the api:
"If the network redirector or the target file system does not support this operation, the function fails with ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION."

Comment: As it turns out, `ReadDirectoryChangesW` works as expected, but `ReadDirectoryChangesExW `does not seem to work on my windows docker container for a bind-directory. Both functions work for running the service locally into the docker container and monitoring a container's folder without any binding.